# Can twilio record data track along with video & audio?

Tags: video, twilio, recording, rtcdatachannel

My application uses the data channel to send a number of types of information between peers during a video call (text messages, button presses, phone orientation, etc).  I need to be able to replay all of this data with the video recording.  I don't see a way to record/playback this data with the twilio API, but don't want to rebuild the functionality if twilio supports this functionality or has thought through the best way to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

The data track is not currently recorded and this not available for composition after the room is complete.